# ActionLink only if a certain condition is met

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

If s = "N/A" then I don't want to use the ActionLink.  In other words, if the inventory item is not currently being used on a project, then don't provide the link (just show N/A instead).  Also, how do I send the link to Projects/Details?  Right now, it will go to "Nails/Projects/Details" instead, because I'm using the NailsController class.

```
            <td class="table-normal-data">
            <%  Dim l As Integer = InStr(item.CurrentProject, " [")
                Dim s As String = item.CurrentProject
                Dim projectID As String = ""
                If l > 0 Then
                    s = Mid(item.CurrentProject, 1, l - 1)
                    projectID = Mid(item.CurrentProject, l + 2, Len(item.CurrentProject) - l - 2)
                Else
                    s = ""
                End If
            %>
            <%: Html.ActionLink(s, "Projects/Details", New With {.id = projectID}) %>
        </td>
```

Comment: I fixed the ActionLink by changing it to: Html.ActionLink(s, "Details","Projects", New With {.id = projectID}, "")

Comment: Also, if s = "N/A", I've added projectID = 0. So the "N/A" will still have a link (which to me is undesired), but the project id will be 0. Hence, clicking the link will yield a page "Project Not Found". Again, I'd rather not have a link for "N/A", but I don't think there's a way to embed the Html.ActionLink inside of the <% %> code tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm much more familiar with MVC3/Razor and C#, but I often do something like this in my views:

```
@if( Model.Flag )
{
    <span>n/a</span>
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink(....
}
```

Basically, you output different stuff through the view depending on the state of the model.